# Penalization 'Best Practice'

Tags: regression, logistic, regularization

Let's take the case of a logistic regression with $n$ observations and $p$ variables. From what I have understood, penalization (Lasso or Elastic Net) is really good for selecting the variables when done with the optimal parameter(s) which is/are determined with cross validation.

My question is:

Should I use the model obtained with the optimal penalization (i.e: the model that takes $x$, the $p$ initial variables which maximize $L(x,y)-\lambda_{1}\|x\|_{1}$ ) ?

Or should I select first $\tilde x$ the $\tilde p$ variables that have non-null coefficients in the penalized model and run a standard logistic regression on it?

The last model will have a better likelihood than the first one, obviously; but is it valid to do it that way?

Comment: The full model will have a better likelihood. Selecting the predictors with the biggest coefficient estimates leads to over-optimism & the point of LASSO (& elastic net) is to re-calibrate the predictions through shrinkage of the coefficient estimate. Undoing that by re-fitting an unpenalized model to the predictors picked by LASSO is unlikely to be helpful in most situations. I'd guess those in which it might be would be those in which stepwise or best-subset methods tend to perform well anyway - when there's a clear enough distinction between the large & the negligible relationships ...

Comment: ... between predictors & response for the selection procedure to be very reliable.